# Taylor Series with differentiator operator

Tags: taylor-expansion

Hi guys can anyone show me how the Taylor series can be converted from:

$$f(x+h)= f(x)+hf'(x)+...$$

to:

$f(x+h)=e^{hD}f(x)$, where $D$ is the differentiation operator.

How does the differentiator operator work?

Comment: Please refer to here to type mathematics formulas: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x+h)=f(x)+h Df(x)+\frac{h^2}{2!} D^2 f(x)+\frac{h^3}{3!} D^3 f(x)+...\\
=(1+hD+\frac{h^2D^2}{2!}+\frac{h^3D^3}{3!}+...)f(x)\\
=e^{hD}f(x)$$

Comment: Oh so D is just the another form of the derivative then

Comment: Ok thanks that helps alot

Comment: In the first and third line, you put the differential operators on the left, as normal. I don't understand why you made the bizarre transposition on the second line.

Comment: You are right. :)

Answer (score 0):

The $D$ operator sends $f$ to $f'$ (as functions). Since 
$$e^t = 1 + t + \frac{t^2}{2!} + \frac{t^3}{3!} + \ldots$$
you get, symbolically at least, 
$$e^{hD} = 1 + hD + \frac{h^2D^2}{2!} + \frac{h^3 D^3}{3!} + \ldots$$.
So
\begin{align}
e^(hD)f(x) 
&= (1 + hD + \frac{h^2D^2}{2!} + \frac{h^3 D^3}{3!} + \ldots) f(x)\\
&= f(x) + hDf(x) + \frac{h^2 D(D(f))(x)}{2!} + \frac{h^3 D(D(D(f)))(x)}{3!} + \ldots \\
&= f(x) + f'(x)h + \frac{f''(x)}{2!}h^2  + \frac{ f'''(x)}{3!}h^3 + \ldots \\
\end{align}
which is the Taylor series.